# URL Encoding escape characters like \n, \t etc

Tags: uri, urlencode, backslash

I have got a String which is encoded in C type encoding(Let me know if there is a better name for that), ie the new lines has been converted into \n and tabs into \t. I want to URLEncode the String but the Encoder is encoding the \ into %5C and leaving n behind. 
For eg: abc\ndef\tghi\njkl is being encoded into 
abc%5Cndef%5Ctghi%5Cnjkl.
Is there any way to change the String in such a way that encoder reads \n as the new line. There are a few hacky and some very hacky ways but I want to avoid them

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a StringEscapeUtils class which has APIs like unescapeJava, unescapeJava which unescapes all these escape characters. Then URL encoding will work correctly. Hope this helps someone facing the same problem.